# paypal in vbulletin

Tags: paypal, payment, vbulletin

I want to integrate paypal payment method in vbulletin. I'm new for both vbulletin and payment gateway. I've complete the process of implement paid subscription from control panel of vbulletin and able to order a subscription. But the problem is that when i order a subscription on the paypal payment page i insert my test account username and password on but returning a message that email and password is not correct. I'm unable to find Where is the mistake ? 
Thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: Without any code, you probably won't get any help. You might also try asking through Paypal's support channels, sounds like a login issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be caused by using sandbox details in real PayPal site, if that is what you mean by "insert my test account username and password". If you want to use the sandbox for your test payments edit class_paypal.php file in vBulletin and replace the instances of www.paypal.com with sandbox.paypal.com, or better, just create 1$ subscription and try with real PayPal address :)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the previous answer.

Inside the vBulletin adminCP you have the ability to test the vBulletin communication with PayPal.

If that fail its a setup problem. If is succeeds its a login issue with your test account.